# django what do i need for authentication after login?

Tags: django, authentication, django-authentication

I followed the example in: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
```

This code doesn't seem to return any token or some sort to the client but just a redirection.

In other codes where django checks authentication, django checks `request.user.is_authenticated`. Do i need to set this by myself?

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
```

To get authenticated by decorators such as `@login_required` or have proper value for `request.user.is_authenticated`, what do I need to send and receive from the client(ReactJS)?

Comment: r u using token based or session based auth and using Django REST framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can return a JsonResponse.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
```

And after successful login

```
return JsonResponse ({
    'token': user.token,
})
```